# Exporting map as PNG without having webmap JSON?

Tags: arcgis-server, export, png

I want to export the image of a map from a page that I don't have a map available.
In other words I need to call a service where I will provide the definition expression of a feature layer, retrieve the graphics and construct a map image.

I am thing of using a template.mxd with the tiled service loaded
and add with some way the queried graphics to that map template.
Then specify in some way the extent around  a specific point so a the max image to be a zoomed state of the map.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your question.  Do you have access to ArcServer Print Tools?  The 'Export Web Map Task" sounds like what you are trying to do...  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00540000001m000000

Comment: Yes i have the access to arcgis server .. Sorry if its not clear. To be more detailed, iwant to get the image of  sone points on  a map with aspecific basemape BUT from a webpage thar does notcontain a map. As a result i have t implement a sort of service that will generate server side , the printed map.

Comment: The points that i want to show on the expoted map, should be coming from afeature service.

Comment: "Export Web Map Task" from the Print Service can generate a map with a basemap,overlay a service with a definition expression, and add point graphics.  Is that what you are attempting? I'm not sure what you mean by "from a webpage thar does notcontain a map"

Comment: I want to get an output  just as the one generated by the export service.. However i donthave a map to construct the web map json. Think ofit as a restful servicethat will get a def expression and will return an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a map to construct the JSON.  You can make it yourself, then POST or GET  to the REST service here (or at your ArcServer): 
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute

See my example below for drawing a basemap: "World_Topo_Map", adding a layer with Definition Expression: "OBJECTID = 19", and adding a point at coordinates: "x":-9529390.916 ,"y":4598848.8713

You will need to substitute as necessary with your coordiates, layers, and extent.  This service will return an image like the one your are seeking.

[Print Service Example](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute?Web_Map_as_JSON=%7B%22mapOptions%22:%20%7B%22showAttribution%22:false,%20%22extent%22:%7B%22xmin%22:-10822676.8359137,%22ymin%22:3807213.95468249,%22xmax%22:-8350405.22470378,%22ymax%22:5470917.28208915,%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:102100%7D%7D,%20%22rotation%22:0,%20%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:102100%7D%7D,%20%22exportOptions%22:%7B%22dpi%22:92,%20%22outputSize%22:[1180,600]%7D,%20%22operationalLayers%22:[%20%7B%20%22id%22:%22CountyBoundary%22,%20%22title%22:%22CountyBoundary%22,%20%22url%22:%22http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Demographics/USA_Diversity_Index/MapServer%22,%20%22opacity%22:1,%20%22minScale%22:null,%20%22maxScale%22:null,%20%20%22visibleLayers%22:%20[4],%20%20%20%22layers%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22:%204,%20%20%22layerDefinition%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%22definitionExpression%22:%20%22OBJECTID%20=%2019%22%20%20%20%7D%20%7D%20]%20%7D,%20%7B%22id%22:%22map_graphics%22,%20%20%20%22opacity%22:1,%20%20%20%22minScale%22:0,%20%20%20%22maxScale%22:0,%20%20%20%22featureCollection%22:%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22layers%22:[%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22layerDefinition%22:%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22:%22pointLayer%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22geometryType%22:%22esriGeometryPoint%22%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22featureSet%22:%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22geometryType%22:%22esriGeometryPoint%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22features%22:[%7B%22geometry%22:%7B%22x%22:-9529390.916%20,%22y%22:4598848.8713,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:102100,%22latestWkid%22:102100%7D%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22symbol%22:%7B%22color%22:[0,255,0,191],%22size%22:7.5,%22angle%22:0,%22xoffset%22:0,%22yoffset%22:0,%22type%22:%22esriSMS%22,%22style%22:%22esriSMSSquare%22,%22outline%22:%7B%22color%22:%20[0,0,0,255],%22width%22:1,%22type%22:%22esriSLS%22,%22style%22:%22esriSLSSolid%22%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D]%7D%7D]%7D%7D%20],%20%22baseMap%22:%7B%22baseMapLayers%22:[%7B%22url%22:%22http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer%22,%22opacity%22:1%7D]%7D%20%7D%20&Format=JPG&Layout_Template=&env:outSR=&env:processSR=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&f=html)